# Tensorflow serving No versions of servable <MODEL> found under base path

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-serving

I was following [this](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/how-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-part-2-containerize-it-db0ad7ca35a7) tutorial to use `tensorflow serving` using my object detection model. I am using [tensorflow object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) for generating the model. I have created a frozen model using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md) exporter (the generated frozen model **works** using python script).

The frozen graph directory has following contents ( nothing on `variables` directory)

> variables/
>
> saved_model.pb

Now when I try to serve the model using the following command,

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=ssd --model_base_path=/serving/ssd_frozen/
```

It always shows me

> ...
>
> tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:421]  (Re-)adding
> model: ssd 2017-08-07 10:22:43.892834: W
> tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:262]
> No versions of servable ssd found under base path /serving/ssd_frozen/
> 2017-08-07 10:22:44.892901: W
> tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:262]
> No versions of servable ssd found under base path /serving/ssd_frozen/
>
> ...

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I had same problem, the reason is because object detection api does not assign version of your model when exporting your detection model. However, tensorflow serving requires you to assign a version number of your detection model, so that you could choose different versions of your models to serve. In your case, you should put your detection model(.pb file and variables folder) under folder:
/serving/ssd_frozen/1/. In this way, you will assign your model to version 1, and tensorflow serving will automatically load this version since you only have one version. By default tensorflow serving will automatically serve the latest version(ie, the largest number of versions).

Note, after you created 1/ folder, the model_base_path is still need to be set to --model_base_path=/serving/ssd_frozen/.

Comment: I know I am coming late to this thread, but could you output what the expected full value of the command should be using his initial command? thanks!

Comment: @contractorwolf It's been two years I cannot recall details, but I believe you do not need to do any modifications on above command in order to get it work. And I also believe Object Detection API should fixed this issue. Sorry for not being very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply anyways @XinyaoWang I did end up figuring out that your answer was right but i didnt understand it fully until I played around and created a numbered folder like you suggested.  Then it worked with the command like you have above.  Much appreciated!

Comment: This was the key part for me: `the model_base_path is still need to be set to --model_base_path=/serving/ssd_frozen/`. I had been including the `/1` (version number directory). Now if I have multiple versions and I don't want it to run the latest one, I'm not sure how this will work.

Answer (score 12):

For new version of tf serving, as you know, it no longer supports the model format used to be exported by SessionBundle but now SavedModelBuilder.

I suppose it's better to restore a session from your older model format and then export it by SavedModelBuilder. You can indicate the version of your model with it.

```
    def export_saved_model(version, path, sess=None):
        tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('version', version, 'version number of the model.')
        tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('work_dir', path, 'your older model  directory.')
        tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('model_dir', '/tmp/model_name', 'saved model directory')
        FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

        # you can give the session and export your model immediately after training 
        if not sess: 
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(path, 'xxx.ckpt.meta'))
            saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(path))

        export_path = os.path.join(
            tf.compat.as_bytes(FLAGS.model_dir),
            tf.compat.as_bytes(str(FLAGS.version)))
        builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

        # define the signature def map here
        # ...

        legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
            signature_def_map={
                'predict_xxx':
                    prediction_signature
            },
            legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op
        )

        builder.save()
        print('Export SavedModel!')
```

you could find main part of the code above in tf serving example.
Finally it will generate the SavedModel in a format that can be served.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a version folder under like - serving/model_name/0000123/saved_model.pb

Answer's above already explained why it is important to keep a version number inside the model folder. Follow below link , here they have  different sets of  built models , you can take it as a reference.

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata

Comment: This answer's value would be greatly increased if you could explain why that helps :) I for example would probably try that out, but still be left wondering why that solves the issue.

Comment: Answer's above explained why it is important to keep a version number inside the model folder.  below link, if you will see, each model has versions like 00000123 https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata

Answer (score 1):

I was doing this on my personal computer running Ubuntu, not Docker. Note I am in a directory called "serving". This is where I saved my folder "mobile_weight". I had to create a new folder, "0000123" inside "mobile_weight". My path looks like serving->mobile_weight->0000123->(variables folder and saved_model.pb)

The command from the tensorflow serving tutorial should look like (Change model_name and your directory):

```
nohup tensorflow_model_server \
 --rest_api_port=8501  \
 --model_name=model_weight  \
 --model_base_path=/home/murage/Desktop/serving/mobile_weight >server.log 2>&1
```

So my entire terminal screen looks like:

```
murage@murage-HP-Spectre-x360-Convertible:~/Desktop/serving$ nohup tensorflow_model_server   --rest_api_port=8501   --model_name=model_weight   --model_base_path=/home/murage/Desktop/serving/mobile_weight >server.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message can also result due to issues with the `--volume` argument.

Ensure your `--volume` mount is actually correct and points to the model's dir, as this is a general '**model not found**' error, but it just seems more complex.

If on windows just use `cmd`, otherwise its easy to accidentally use linux file path and linux separators in cygwin or gitbash. Even with the correct file structure you can get OP's error if you don't use the windows absolute path.

```
#using cygwin
$ echo $TESTDATA
/home/username/directory/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata

$ docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v "$TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two tensorflow/serving
2021-01-22 20:12:28.995834: W tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:267] No versions of servable half_plus_two found under base path /models/half_plus_two. Did you forget to name your leaf directory as a number (eg. '/1/')?
```

Then calling the same command with the same unchanged file structure but with the full windows path using windows file separators, and it works:

```
#using cygwin
$ export TESTDATA="$(cygpath -w "/home/username/directory/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata")"
$ echo $TESTDATA
C:\Users\username\directory\serving\tensorflow_serving\servables\tensorflow\testdata

$ docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v "$TESTDATA\\saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two tensorflow/serving 
2021-01-22 21:10:49.527049: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:740] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: half_plus_two version: 1}
```