# AWS SageMaker TensorFlow Serving - Endpoint failure - CloudWatch log ref: "NET_LOG: Entering the event loop ..."

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nginx, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

It's my first time using sagemaker to serve my own custom tensorflow model so I have been using the medium articles to get me started:

[How to Create a TensorFlow Serving Container for AWS SageMaker](https://medium.com/ml-bytes/how-to-create-a-tensorflow-serving-container-for-aws-sagemaker-4853842c9751)
[How to Push a Docker Image to AWS ECS Repository](https://medium.com/ml-bytes/how-to-push-a-docker-image-to-aws-ecs-repository-fba579a9f419?)
[How to Deploy an AWS SageMaker Container Using TensorFlow Serving](https://medium.com/ml-bytes/how-to-deploy-an-aws-sagemaker-container-using-tensorflow-serving-4587dad76169?)
[How to Make Predictions Against a SageMaker Endpoint Using TensorFlow Serving](https://medium.com/ml-bytes/how-to-make-predictions-against-a-sagemaker-endpoint-using-tensorflow-serving-8b423b9b316a)

I managed to create my serving container, push it successfully to ECR, and create the sagemaker model from my docker image. However, when i tried to create the endpoints it started creating but after 3-5 minutes ended with the failure message:

> "The primary container for production variant Default did not pass the
>   ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint."

[Failure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXCnK.png)

I then checked my cloud watch logs which looked like this...

[CloudWatch Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdp4S.png)

...ending with "NET_LOG: Entering the event loop ..."

I tried to google more about this log message in relation to deploying sagemaker models with tf-serving, but could not find any helpful solutions.

To give more context, before running into this problem I encountered 2 other issues:

> 1. "FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a file-system access error:
>      Could not find base path
>
>    ‹MODEL_PATH›/‹MODEL_NAME›/ for ‹MODEL_NAME›"
> 2. "No versions of servable  found under base path"

Both of which I managed to solve using the following links:

[[Documentation] TensorFlowModel endpoints need the `export/Servo` folder structure, but this is not documented](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/599)
[Failed Reason: The primary container for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping health check.](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/697)

It's also worth noting that my Tensorflow model was created using TF version 2.0 (hence why I needed the docker container). I solely used AWS CLI to carry out my tensorflow serving instead of the sagemaker SDK.

Here are snippets of my shell scripts:

**nginx.config**

```
events {
    # determines how many requests can simultaneously be served
    # https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-nginx-configuration
    # for more information
    worker_connections 2048;
}

http {
  server {
    # configures the server to listen to the port 8080
    # Amazon SageMaker sends inference requests to port 8080.
    # For more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html#your-algorithms-inference-code-container-response
    listen 8080 deferred;

    # redirects requests from SageMaker to TF Serving
    location /invocations {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8501/v1/models/pornilarity_model:predict;
    }

    # Used by SageMaker to confirm if server is alive.
    # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html#your-algorithms-inference-algo-ping-requests
    location /ping {
      return 200 "OK";
    }
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# RUN pip install sagemaker-containers

# Installing NGINX, used to reverse proxy the predictions from SageMaker to TF Serving
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nginx git

# Copy our model folder to the container 
# NB: Tensorflow serving requires you manually assign version numbering to models e.g. model_path/1/
# see below links: 

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544928/tensorflow-serving-no-versions-of-servable-model-found-under-base-path
# https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/599
COPY pornilarity_model /opt/ml/model/export/Servo/1/

# Copy NGINX configuration to the container
COPY nginx.conf /opt/ml/code/nginx.conf

# Copies the hosting code inside the container
# COPY serve.py /opt/ml/code/serve.py

# Defines serve.py as script entrypoint
# ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM serve.py

# starts NGINX and TF serving pointing to our model
ENTRYPOINT service nginx start | tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 \
 --model_name=pornilarity_model \
 --model_base_path=/opt/ml/model/export/Servo/
```

**Build and push**

```
%%sh

# The name of our algorithm
ecr_repo=sagemaker-tf-serving
docker_image=sagemaker-tf-serving

cd container

# chmod a+x container/serve.py

account=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)

# Get the region defined in the current configuration (default to us-west-2 if none defined)
region=$(aws configure get region)
region=${region:-eu-west-2}

fullname="${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repo}:latest"

# If the repository doesn't exist in ECR, create it.

aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names "${ecr_repo}" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "${ecr_repo}" > /dev/null
fi

# Get the login command from ECR and execute it directly
$(aws ecr get-login --region ${region} --no-include-email)

# Build the docker image locally with the image name and then push it to ECR
# with the full name.

docker build -t ${docker_image} .
# docker tag ${docker_image} ${fullname}
docker tag ${docker_image}:latest ${fullname}

docker push ${fullname}
```

**Create SageMaker Model**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CONTAINER_NAME="Pornilarity-Container"
MODEL_NAME=pornilarity-model-v1

# the role named created with
# https://gist.github.com/mvsusp/599311cb9f4ee1091065f8206c026962
ROLE_NAME=AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20191202T133391

# the name of the image created with
# https://gist.github.com/mvsusp/07610f9cfecbec13fb2b7c77a2e843c4
ECS_IMAGE_NAME=sagemaker-tf-serving
# the role arn of the role
EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN=$(aws iam get-role --role-name ${ROLE_NAME} | jq -r .Role.Arn)

# the ECS image URI
ECS_IMAGE_URI=$(aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-name ${ECS_IMAGE_NAME} |\
jq -r .repositories[0].repositoryUri)

# defines the SageMaker model primary container image as the ECS image
PRIMARY_CONTAINER="ContainerHostname=${CONTAINER_NAME},Image=${ECS_IMAGE_URI}"

# Createing the model
aws sagemaker create-model --model-name ${MODEL_NAME} \
--primary-container=${PRIMARY_CONTAINER}  --execution-role-arn ${EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN}
```

**Endpoint config**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MODEL_NAME=pornilarity-model-v1

ENDPOINT_CONFIG_NAME=pornilarity-model-v1-config

ENDPOINT_NAME=pornilarity-v1-endpoint

PRODUCTION_VARIANTS="VariantName=Default,ModelName=${MODEL_NAME},"\
"InitialInstanceCount=1,InstanceType=ml.c5.large"

aws sagemaker create-endpoint-config --endpoint-config-name ${ENDPOINT_CONFIG_NAME} \
--production-variants ${PRODUCTION_VARIANTS}

aws sagemaker create-endpoint --endpoint-name ${ENDPOINT_NAME} \
--endpoint-config-name ${ENDPOINT_CONFIG_NAME}
```

**Docker Container Folder Structure**

```
├── container
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── nginx.conf
│   ├── pornilarity_model
│   │   ├── assets
│   │   ├── saved_model.pb
│   │   └── variables
│   │       ├── variables.data-00000-of-00002
│   │       ├── variables.data-00001-of-00002
│   │       └── variables.index
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You web server on path

> <public_address>/ping

must have exposed liveness response, with returning 200 if everything is running. Now it is missing and Sagemaker does not see it as a valid container for inference. It is that simple :)

There are containers already with the web server doing this for you, in your case Tensorfolow serving container is publicly available at:

```
763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-inference:2.4.1-cpu-py37-ubuntu18.04
```

This is example for us-east and for CPU type of inference.
You can add the model /opt/ml/model/ as you did in your example docker.

For all the available containers look at [deep learning containers at AWS](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md)