# Tensorflow Serving: no versions of servable half_plus_two found under base path /models

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm doing Tensorflow Serving with Docker (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker) for docs). Server runs on our infra here. I've succeeded at requesting my model when the command to run the container is something like:

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 \
   --model_name=${MODEL_NAME} --model_base_path=${MODEL_BASE_PATH}/${MODEL_NAME}
```

A curl request to the server returns the expected answer. Problem occurs when I try to use the model_config_file parameter. Command:

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 \
   --model_config_file=/serving/models.conf
```

Config file is:

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name: "half_plus_two",
    base_path: "/models/",
    model_platform: "tensorflow"
  }
}
```

When I run the container with this command, I get the error:

```
No versions of servable half_plus_two found under base path /models/
```

(I've also tried to remove the trailing backslash on the base_path with no more success). I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544928/tensorflow-serving-no-versions-of-servable-model-found-under-base-path) on SO that reminds us to use a version under model dir and I have one. My /models dir is:

```
models
 |
  - half_plus_two
        |
         - 1
           |
            - saved_model.pb
            - variables
            - assets
```

Someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same thing on Windows 10. I finally:

1. Noticed that I forgot to clone the tensorflow/serving [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving) to my local machine
2. Ran on Ubuntu-wsl-2 console, as using Windows command line, I could convince docker to correctly map the container's `/models/half_plus_two` to my local path (the `-v` option in the following command):

> docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 
> -v "$TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" 
> -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two 
> tensorflow/serving &